# Ajax request on document the ready will cause slow loading jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a project that I make with so many ajax request on `document.ready`. More over i also have ajax request for every database transaction i have. I have a js file where i have ajax request and for every ajax request i have a php page where i handle the database things. For the ajax request that i send on `document.ready` those are the request to populate select option that the data are from database.

My Question:

1. Is there a limit on how many ajax request i should send.
2. Will the number of ajax request slow down my project.
3. What are the ways to avoid my project be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a limit on how many ajax request i should send.

The browser limits it to two requests at any given time.

> Will the number of ajax request slow down my project.

No they won't slow down the project. It's async so not an issue. But if the user is having slower internet connection / server takes time to respond then the drop down menu will take time to load.

> What are the ways to avoid my project be slow.

Instead of firing all requests at once, only if the data is required then fire the ajax event. Like for example, if the drop down is present in third page and not all users will be visiting the page. Then load that data only when users visit that page.

Comment: how do i know that the user is visiting which page?i want to add this to my ajax request this sound good.

Comment: is it a single page application?

Comment: Assume you're showing a form which contains your drop down menu. Then on click of some button , you might be loading that form. So at that time make the ajax request as well. Need not eager load all data

Comment: Any other info you need @Pekka?

Comment: as far sa you have explained it i think i understand all of it. By the way i dont use form i use php page then i change page when i go to other pages so there i will accept your answer thank you for sharing these info